# Unable to create new user from Admin "New User" page ... Drupal 7

Tags: users

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Submit');
}
```

I override the name of the submit button using customs module.

User registrations works fine, but when I'm trying to create a user through admin interface, fill out the form and click "Submit", I get redirected to "user/list" page, user doesn't get created, and the text on the top of the page is actually from "create user":

Any idea why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This is a core bug. You can read about it [here](https://drupal.org/node/208790). What you can do is to translate "Create new account" string or use [String Overrides module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).